# Using pipe() and execvp() killing my program

Tags: c, shell

My program is killed when I run this bit of code but I can't seem to figure out why.

```
int pipefd[2];
pipe(pipefd);
pid = fork();

if(pid == 0){                      //child process, receives data from pipe for execution   
  close(0);
  dup(pipefd[0]);                       
  close(pipefd[1]);
  execvp(pipeCom2[0], pipeCom2);
}
else if (pid > 1){                //parent process writes data to pipe for execution 
  close(1);
  dup(pipefd[1]);                                      
  close(pipefd[0]);
  execvp(pipeCom1[0], pipeCom1);
  waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
}
```

I've been testing with cat project1.c | grep include command. It executes properly displaying all include statements in my program.

so pipeCom1 contains {"cat", "project1.c"}

and pipeCom2 contains  {"grep", "include"}

Earlier in the program I override output with this code and return to normal at the end of my program. So when the process is killed output is messed up.

```
newConfig.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON| ECHOE | ECHO);
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &newConfig);
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are not closing enough pipe file descriptors.  If you duplicate a descriptor to standard input or output, you should close _both_ of the pipe descriptors. Also, the parent process contains an `execvp` call; the following code is only executed if the exec fails.

Comment: If you need the terminal reset, either do it before one of the exec calls, or create two children and have the parent close all its pipe descriptors and wait for the children to finish (die) before resetting the terminal. Think about signal handling. Resetting the terminal before executing the other programs is simpler.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler which other pipe file descriptors should I be closing?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

#### Closing pipes

You are not closing enough pipe file descriptors. If you duplicate a descriptor to standard input or output, you should close both of the pipe descriptors.

> Which other pipe file descriptors should I be closing?

You have:

```
int pipefd[2];
pipe(pipefd);
pid = fork();

if (pid == 0)                      //child process, receives data from pipe for execution
{   
    close(0);
    dup(pipefd[0]);                       
    close(pipefd[1]);
    execvp(pipeCom2[0], pipeCom2);
}
else if (pid > 1)                 //parent process writes data to pipe for execution
{
    close(1);
    dup(pipefd[1]);                                      
    close(pipefd[0]);
    execvp(pipeCom1[0], pipeCom1);
    waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
}
```

You need to close both `pipefd[0]` and `pipefd[1]` in both sets of code, after calling `dup()`.  You could use `dup2()` instead of `dup()`, too; that is often simpler.

In this program with the trial pipeline, there's a decent chance all will be OK without adding the missing `close()` operations.  However, in general, it is crucial you close the unneeded pipe descriptors as an open descriptor means that a process won't get the EOF it expects, or it won't get a SIGPIPE signal or a write error when it should, because a process has the wrong end of the pipe still open.

#### Parent invokes `execvp()`

Also, the parent process contains an `execvp()` call; the following code is only executed if the exec fails.  When a process runs `execvp()` (or any of the other `exec*()` functions, the call only returns if the execute operation fails.

If you need the terminal reset, either do it before one of the exec calls, or create two children and have the parent close all its pipe descriptors and wait for the children to finish (die) before resetting the terminal. Think about signal handling. Resetting the terminal before executing the other programs is simpler.

> Earlier in the program I override output with this code and return to normal at the end of my program. So when the process is killed output is messed up.
>
> ```
> newConfig.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON| ECHOE | ECHO);
> tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &newConfig);
> ```

Assuming you have an `oldConfig` with the output from `tcgetattr()`, you should do:

```
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &oldConfig);
```

before the parent process runs `execvp()`.

#### Null terminated lists of command arguments

You say:

> pipeCom1 contains {"cat", "project1.c"}
>
> and pipeCom2 contains {"grep", "include"}

It is crucial for correct operation that both `pipeCom1` and `pipeCom2` have a null (pointer) terminated list of argument strings.  For example, you might use hard-wired argument lists like these:

```
char *pipeCom1[] = { "cat", "project1.c", 0 };
char *pipeCom2[] = { "grep", "include", 0 };
```

You can write NULL in place of 0 if you prefer.

#### Report error and exit when `execvp()` fails

You need to consider what should happen after `execvp()` fails.  The correct answer is seldom 'continue as if nothing went wrong' (which is what your code does).

You should consider reporting an error to standard error.  You should normally exit with a failure status, either using `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or `_exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` or some relative of these.

#### Assembling all these changes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct termios oldConfig;
    struct termios newConfig;
    tcgetattr(0, &oldConfig);           // Error check omitted
    newConfig = oldConfig;
    newConfig.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON| ECHOE | ECHO);
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &newConfig);  // Error check omitted

    /* Do stuff without echoing enabled */

    /* Now do some execution */

    char *pipeCom1[] = { "cat", "project1.c", 0 };
    char *pipeCom2[] = { "grep", "include", 0 };

    int pipefd[2];                      // Error check omitted
    pipe(pipefd);
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)                       //child process
    {   
        close(0);
        dup(pipefd[0]);                       
        close(pipefd[1]);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        execvp(pipeCom2[0], pipeCom2);
        perror(pipeCom2[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if (pid > 1)                   //parent process
    {
        close(1);
        dup(pipefd[1]);                                      
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &oldConfig);
        execvp(pipeCom1[0], pipeCom1);
        perror(pipeCom1[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

#### Sample run

Assuming `project1.c` is a copy of the source code above, the output from the command is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
    char *pipeCom2[] = { "grep", "include", 0 };
```

and the terminal is in the correct mode after the process ends.